# php replace all string occurances with values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string containing image ID's and an array which has for the keys the old image ID's and for the values new image ID's.

I need to search through the content for old ones and replace with the new ones.

I've done this

```
<?php

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, image="150" consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro voluptatibus omnis nulla quis mollitia dicta quasi voluptatum totam,
labore doloremque ea fugit consectetur, itaque, ab et odio, est iusto recusandae suscipit? Dignissimos veniam recusandae, magnam, dolor omnis, image="6"
 eveniet laboriosam quas culpa voluptate at officia in natus repellendus assumenda beatae illo repudiandae earum necessitatibus fugit, 
quo error. <span style="padding-top:150px">Esse minima</span>, aut architecto, doloribus quos veritatis reprehenderit.
 Temporibus vitae voluptatibus ea ad similique perspiciatis sed doloribus explicabo error asperiores ab, id aspernatur image="235" eum ducimus magni rerum veniam voluptates, ipsum voluptatum repudiandae dolorum quisquam voluptatem. 
Doloribus nulla voluptate architecto ipsam sed voluptas, maiores rem sequi eos voluptatum iusto rerum odio sapiente sunt minima, image="65" consequuntur aliquid dolor impedit hic. Beatae perspiciatis, incidunt necessitatibus
 voluptas earum cumque, in asperiores id ipsum ducimus veritatis laboriosam eveniet ipsa accusamus! Nulla quasi porro sunt suscipit quibusdam velit
 itaque, voluptates, soluta quaerat consectetur eos doloribus, fugiat quisquam. Quos, ad, dolorum.
';

$array = array(
    '150' => 4025,
    '6'   => 4026,
    '235' => 4027,
    '65'  => 4028,
);

preg_match_all( '/image=\"(\d+)\"/', $string, $matches_image );

if ( '' !== $matches_image[1] && ! empty( $matches_image[1] ) ) {
    foreach ( $matches_image[1] as $key => $matched_image_id ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $matched_image_id, $array ) ) {
            $string = str_replace( $matched_image_id, $array[ $matched_image_id ], $string );
        }
    }
}
```

But if you `print_r` the `$string` you'll notice that it replaces every occurrence of the id (as it should), but that will also replace the top padding in a span (for instance). So at the end I get top padding of 4025px, which is not good :D

I was thinking of first replacing the matched array that finds the whole matched pattern (`image='150'`) with the correct ID and then match that replaced values in the content.

But I'm stuck.

Comment: *but that will also replace the top padding in a span* - can not reproduce. I've just tested your code and it outputs `<span style="padding-top:150px">` within other text

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tested it in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it replaced the padding as well [image](http://imgur.com/a/RIA6a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `str_replace()` will replace any instance of `$matched_image_id` in the string, not just the ones inside the `image='...'` strings. You need to make it more specific:

```
str_replace("image=\"$matched_image_id\"", "image=\"{$array[$matched_image_id]}\"", $string);
```

But you can do the whole thing with `preg_replace_callback()` so you only replace the parts that match the regexp. The callback function can look up the replacement of the ID in the array.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/image="(\d+)"/', function($match) use ($array) {
    return "image=\"{$array[$match[1]]}\"";
}, $string);
```

Comment: Actually this seems to does the trick. Let me check on the real string :)

Comment: @AlexBlex I've added an explanation of the problem in the original string, and showed how it could be fixed there.

Comment: Does not work for me but this does `preg_replace_callback('/image=\"(\d+)\"/'` THe image attr is `image="999"`

Comment: This `str_replace("image='$matched_image_id'", "image='{$array[$matched_image_id]}'", $string);
` is something I never thought of doing tbh, but the second solution looks cleaner :D

Comment: @RiggsFolly I noticed the quotes, but I have replaced them :)

Comment: I thought they were single quotes because you escaped them, and there's no need to escape double quotes inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: Originally they are single quotes, but phptester kept stripping them out, so I added double quotes. So in either case your code helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but it works

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, image="150" consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro voluptatibus omnis nulla quis mollitia dicta quasi voluptatum totam,
labore doloremque ea fugit consectetur, itaque, ab et odio, est iusto recusandae suscipit? Dignissimos veniam recusandae, magnam, dolor omnis, image="6"
 eveniet laboriosam quas culpa voluptate at officia in natus repellendus assumenda beatae illo repudiandae earum necessitatibus fugit, 
quo error. <span style="padding-top:150px">Esse minima</span>, aut architecto, doloribus quos veritatis reprehenderit.
 Temporibus vitae voluptatibus ea ad similique perspiciatis sed doloribus explicabo error asperiores ab, id aspernatur image="235" eum ducimus magni rerum veniam voluptates, ipsum voluptatum repudiandae dolorum quisquam voluptatem. 
Doloribus nulla voluptate architecto ipsam sed voluptas, maiores rem sequi eos voluptatum iusto rerum odio sapiente sunt minima, image="65" consequuntur aliquid dolor impedit hic. Beatae perspiciatis, incidunt necessitatibus
 voluptas earum cumque, in asperiores id ipsum ducimus veritatis laboriosam eveniet ipsa accusamus! Nulla quasi porro sunt suscipit quibusdam velit
 itaque, voluptates, soluta quaerat consectetur eos doloribus, fugiat quisquam. Quos, ad, dolorum.
';

$array = array(
    '150' => 4025,
    '6'   => 4026,
    '235' => 4027,
    '65'  => 4028,
);

$find = array_keys($array);
foreach ($find as &$f) { $f = 'image="'.$f; }
$repl = array_values($array);
foreach ($repl as &$r) { $r = 'image="'.$r; }
print_r($find);print_r($repl);

$s1 = str_replace($find, $repl, $string);
echo $s1;
```

Result

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, image="4025" consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro voluptatibus omnis nulla quis mollitia dicta quasi voluptatum totam,
labore doloremque ea fugit consectetur, itaque, ab et odio, est iusto recusandae suscipit? Dignissimos veniam recusandae, magnam, dolor omnis, image="4026"
 eveniet laboriosam quas culpa voluptate at officia in natus repellendus assumenda beatae illo repudiandae earum necessitatibus fugit, 
quo error. <span style="padding-top:150px">Esse minima</span>, aut architecto, doloribus quos veritatis reprehenderit.
 Temporibus vitae voluptatibus ea ad similique perspiciatis sed doloribus explicabo error asperiores ab, id aspernatur image="4027" eum ducimus magni rerum veniam voluptates, ipsum voluptatum repudiandae dolorum quisquam voluptatem. 
Doloribus nulla voluptate architecto ipsam sed voluptas, maiores rem sequi eos voluptatum iusto rerum odio sapiente sunt minima, image="40265" consequuntur aliquid dolor impedit hic. Beatae perspiciatis, incidunt necessitatibus
 voluptas earum cumque, in asperiores id ipsum ducimus veritatis laboriosam eveniet ipsa accusamus! Nulla quasi porro sunt suscipit quibusdam velit
 itaque, voluptates, soluta quaerat consectetur eos doloribus, fugiat quisquam. Quos, ad, dolorum.
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do this with str_replace & by changing your array a bit :

```
$string = 'Lorem ...';

$array = array(
    'image="150' => 'image="4025',
    'image="6'   => 'image="4026',
    'image="235' => 'image="4027',
    'image="65'  => 'image="4028',
);

$new_string = str_replace(array_keys($array), $array, $string);
```

Comment: Can't change the array I'm afraid

Comment: @dingo_d, why not? sure you can.

Comment: @dingo_d Couldn't you create a new array derived from the original array?

Comment: I'm using a predefined array, that is created waaaaay up in the code (in the original code that is), so I can't just change it without having to change my other code ;)

Comment: You could just store the changed array in another variable